# scripting $_POST variable on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a registration form that allows a user to register as many people as they want.  For example I don't know ahead of time if 1 person is registering or if 500 are.  So on the server side if I have 3 people registering at once I need to access all the first names of a person by `$_POST['first0']` `$_POST['first1']` and `$_POST['first2']`. So here is my database query.

```
    for ($i=0; $i < runners; $i++) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$usertable." VALUES (".$_POST['first'.$i].", ".$_POST['last'.$i].", ".$_POST['age'.$i].",
        ".$_POST['gender'.$i].", ".$_POST['email'.$i]." , ".$_POST['phone'.$i]." , ".$_POST['address'.$i]." ,
        ".$_POST['city'.$i]." , ".$_POST['state'.$i]." , ".$_POST['zip'.$i]." , ".$_POST['type'.$i]." , ".$_POST['tshirt'.$i].")";
```

My query is not working so I know my quotes and apostrophes are incorrect would anyone be able to show me the correct way to accomplish this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you are getting into deep trouble if you are going to trust users not to post SQL injection code and unwanted quotes.

Comment: sql injection capital right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, posted data is a lot easier to work with if your form entries use the array syntax, i.e.:

```
<label>First: <input name="first[]" value="" /></label>
<label>Last: <input name="last[]" value="" /></label>
<label>Age: <input name="age[]" value="" /></label>
<label>Gender: 
    <input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="m" />Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="f" />Female
</label>
```

Then, in your code, values like `$_POST['first']` are an array of values.

Secondly, you should look at prepared statements. Observe:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (first, last, age, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

foreach ($_POST['first'] as $index => $value) {
    $stmt->execute(array(
        $value,
        $_POST['last'][$index],
        $_POST['age'][$index],
        $_POST['gender'][$index],
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is instead of using user0, user1, user2, ...
You can actually past the html input text as an array.
e.g:

```
<!-- first user field -->
<input type="text" name="users[]" />
<!-- second user field -->
<input type="text" name="users[]" />
<!-- third user field -->
<input type="text" name="users[]" />
```

So your php will look something like this:

```
$users = $_POST['users'];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO $userTable VALUES ('".mysqli_escape_string($user)."');
}
```

Of course the code above is only an example with 1 variable you can apply them to all other variables.

Cheers.

Comment: `mysql_*` is depreciated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should prevent SQL injection while interacting with database.

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Here is the updated query.

```
 for ($i=0; $i < runners; $i++) {
         $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['first'.$i]);
         $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['last'.$i]);
         $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['age'.$i]);
         $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['gender'.$i]);
         $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email'.$i]);
         $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'.$i]);
         $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address'.$i]);
         $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['city'.$i]);
         $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['state'.$i]);
         $zip= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['zip'.$i]);
         $type= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['type'.$i]);
         $tshirt= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['tshirt'.$i]);

        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$usertable." VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname ."', ".$age .",
       '".$gender ."', '".$email ."', ".$phone." , '".$address ."' ,
        '".$city."' , '".$state."' , ".$zip." , '".$type."' , '".$tshirt."')";
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is depreciated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @plain jane you are missing a lot of single quotes.
You can use PHP's variable replacement capability like the following. This is much more readable code.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $usertable VALUES ('{$_POST['first'.$i]}', '{$_POST['last'.$i]}', '{$_POST['age'.$i]}',
    '{$_POST['gender'.$i]}', '{$_POST['email'.$i]}', '{$_POST['phone'.$i]}', '{$_POST['address'.$i]}' ,
    '{$_POST['city'.$i]}' , '{$_POST['state'.$i]}' , '{$_POST['zip'.$i]}' , '{$_POST['type'.$i]}' , '{$_POST['tshirt'.$i]}')";
```

**Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and can be easily broken with just a single quote in any posted field. even `St'Mary` as first name will break your code. To prevent this

1. Please validate/sanitize your posted values
2. Use Prepared statements instead of direct query string.